# Gmail History API not filtering based on label Id when using INBOX

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

When we use /history api and add filter base on label and historyType as messageAdded
The API returns to us messages which are added in DRAFT, SENT as well.
Why is this behavior happening? How can we add the fix for the same?

curl --location 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{{userID}}/history?historyTypes=messageAdded&labelId=INBOX&maxResults=500&startHistoryId=' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY' 
--header 'Accept: application/json'